# FileWriter запись/создание файла

Tags: java, файлы, filewriter

Пишу Класс для создание/чтения файлов properties. Каждый файл находится в своей папке. Необходимо реализовать получение пути запуска программы и собрать путь. Все хорошо кроме одного при передачи пути в FileWriter выдает ошибку (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома). Как побороть. Вот собранный путь `file:\E:\Project Java\Project Idea\esteamerbase\out\artifacts\web_ee_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\CashBack\cashback_config.properties` с ним ошибка. Если всунуть напрямую конструктору Filewriter этот путь то все работает.

Код которым пользуюсь

```
public void setListSumProperties(List<SumProperties> listSumProperies)throws IOException{
    String path = "/CashBack/cashback_config.properties";//Папка с config
    path = URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getResource(path).toString(),"utf-8");//Преобразованный путь без %20
    System.out.println(path);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);
    for (SumProperties sum:listSumProperies
         ) {
        fileWriter.write(sum.getProcent()+"="+sum.getProcent_value()+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriter.write(sum.getSum()+"="+sum.getSum_value()+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = null;

try {

    output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

    // set the properties value
    prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
    prop.setProperty("dbuser", "mkyong");
    prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

    // save properties to project root folder
    prop.store(output, null);

} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85930/discussion-on-answer-by---filewriter---).